# In Angular ngClass can we combine more than one conditions?

Tags: ionic4, angular8

`[ngClass]="{'hasDocument': item.communication_file != '', 'no_Doc': item.communication_file == '' }">`

For example, how to do the following?

`[ngClass]="{'hasDocument': item.communication_file != '' && item.communication_file != null, 'no_Doc': item.communication_file == '' }">`

Is it possible to do so? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: you're already using the correct syntax

Answer (score 0):

But you are missing "()" in this braces define "True" and "False".

```
    [ngClass]="{'hasDocument': (item.communication_file != '' && item.communication_file != null), 'no_Doc': item.communication_file == '' }"
```

if you want to use more than one condition use braces.